# Enumerate windows on taskbar in Windows XP without P/Invoke using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, taskbar

Is there any method of retrieving only windows on the taskbar?

I want to make a custom "taskbar" that will group APPs in any order (not just in common order like default windows task grouping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use P/Invoke. Unfortunately, there is no standard way to determine whether a window would appear in the taskbar (or in alt+tab): you can only guess.

Here's a pretty old example in VB: http://www.thescarms.com/VBasic/alttab.aspx

And in [OnTopReplica](http://ontopreplica.codeplex.com/), I implemented it in a similar manner. You can take a look at the [source code](http://ontopreplica.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) (check out `OnTopReplica/WindowSeekers/TaskWindowSeeker.cs`).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, without P/Invoke -- no.

However, if you only care about managed, Windows Forms windows that are within your .NET process, you can loop through `Application.OpenForms` and examine properties, especially `Form.ShowInTaskbar`. For WPF, it is `Application.Windows`.

Comment: I want to duplicate taskbar items. So far, with p/invoke, I'm accurate at guessing, but it's only guesses. For example, calculator is not an app window. Even though it shows up in the taskbar, I have to explicitly check for the string "Calculator" which is not good code. I was hoping there was a way to know for sure, but I can't find it.